GA4 and MC Integration - Additional Attributes in Data Extension
We are testing the integration between GA4 and MC. We have completed testing up to the configuration of integration settings and the creation of GA Audience in DE.
The attributes within the DE are SubscriberKey, SubscriberId, and AllowPersonalizedAds.

What information is the AllowPersonalizedAds field in the DE based on?
Is there a way to add other attributes to the DE?
Are there other methods to import behavioral information from GA4 to MC? (Currently, we are considering exporting rows from BigQuery to MC, but we are inquiring if there is a direct integration method or any other alternatives available.)

Thanks in advance!
